# Retrieving value for a key returns null in Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase

I want to fetch all the values which are inside specific child node in android firebase. I tried hard-coding the value of the specific child node but the value returns as "null" though there are values present. The log doesn't print any value either.

[image: firebase storage]

I want both key and value which are under the child "KiOPo3fZzMmzUkbR74Z"

This is my code,

```
      databaseReferenceappmnt=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments");
      databaseReferenceappmnt.child("KiOPo3fZzMmzUkbR74Z").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                String post_image = (String)dataSnapshot.child("anu").getValue();
                String post_key =(String)dataSnapshot.child("anu").getKey();
                if (post_image != null) {
                    Log.d("post_image", post_image);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("nullvalue","null");
                }
                Log.d("post_key", post_key);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("exeptipom",e+"");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

It prints the key but the value is null. Its going in "else" part of the condition. I don't know where I am wrong. I am new to firebase.Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getters and setters to set and get the values.

It easy to get values using getters.

```
databaseReferenceappmnt=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments");
databaseReferenceappmnt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
                Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                String post_image = model.getPostImage();
                String post_key = model.getPostKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("nullvalue","null");
            }
            Log.d("post_key", post_key);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("exeptipom",e+"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Your Model.java should be like this

```
public class Model {

    private String postImage;
    private String postKey;
    public Model(){
    }
    public void setPostImage(String postImage) {
        this.postImage = postImage;
    }

    public String getPostImage() {
        return postImage;
    }

    public void setPostKey(String postKey) {
        this.postKey = postKey;
    }

    public String getPostKey() {
        return postKey;
   }                                                                           
}
```

Setting values using setters

```
Model model = new Model();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments");
model.setPostImage(yourEditText1.getText().toString());
model.setPostKey(yourEditText2.getText().toString())
     try {
            databaseReference.push().setValue(model, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    //Your code
                  }
            });
        }
        catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            Log.d("Error:",e.getMessage());
        }
```